# Pendulum usage in gravitational wave detectors

Tags: gravitational-waves, gravitational-wave-detectors

I've read that pendulums are (or were) used to calibrate the distance between the mirrors in a gravitational wave detector. In principle pendulums are supposed to be moving in just one plane no matter what is the rotation of the Earth, but I do not understand how do they make to compensate for the energy losses (for example in the elasticity of the thread, etc...) to make them suitable to perform this calibration, can somebody give a good reference?